# Username or Password incorrect on opening an exefile programatically

Tags: c#, process, exe

I have added a network drive, and typed in the credentials for it, in my explore. 
I've made an application in c# that have to execute a file on that specific networkdrive.

The thing is that it's working perfect on my own client machine, but when I install it on my collegues machines and i've made the same network drive on their client, it gives me an exception error saying that the username or password are incorrect.

System.IO.IOException: Brugernavnet eller adgangskoden er forkert.

ved System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

ved System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

Code:

```
File.WriteAllText(demoPath846 + @"\xmo.ini", "[system]\r\nInstanceid=846\r\nconnectionstring=" + constr846 + "\r\n[environment]\r\nA6_DRV_EDI=" + demoPath846 + "\\edi\\ \r\nA6_DRV_USER=" + demoPath846 + "\r\n\r\n[update]\r\nurl=http://10.10.62.104/xmoads/1.0 \r\ntimeout=86400000");
            string startfile846 = demoPath846 + @"\xmo.exe"; 

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = demoPath846;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = startfile846;
            p.Start();
```

Something makes me think that it somehow have something to do with the rights to the path. But the path are shared to "everyone" and with both read/write access :/

Comment: You need to translate the error message in English. If the location is shared for all then why you need to enter credentials when you explore it,?

Comment: I think i've found the issue.
The networkshare is unnecesary when i actually give the UNC path in the variable "startfile846" My new issue though is to use the username and password when I run the process via the UNC path...